# set opacity for loading overlay

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I created a `LoadingOverlay` component managed by `Vuex`. The `state` represents its visibility. The current overlay component uses this code

```
<template>
  <v-dialog value="true" transition="false" fullscreen hide-overlay scrollable>
    <v-card>
      <v-layout justify-center align-center fill-height>
        <v-progress-circular :size="80" :width="5" indeterminate color="primary"></v-progress-circular>
      </v-layout>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "LoadingOverlay"
};
</script>
```

I created an example showing a demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/j7jjrpw83

I would like to setup `opacity` for the overlay. Currently the background is *white* and the view gets fully covered. I want to have an `opacity` of **0.7** for the overlay background.

Do I have to use my own CSS or is there a ready to use `opacity` attribute that I can add to the overlay component?

I know I could use `color="transparent"` but this would be too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too sure if this is the best "Vue" way to do it as I've never used Vue, but you can set the color on the v-card to have a translucent background colour:

```
<v-card color="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)">
  <v-layout justify-center align-center fill-height> 
    <v-progress-circular :size="80" :width="5" indeterminate color="primary"></v-progress-circular>
  </v-layout>
</v-card>
```

See [fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/6l0k65990z)

Or even using style and opacity:

```
<v-card style="opacity: 0.7">
  <v-layout justify-center align-center fill-height>
    <v-progress-circular :size="80" :width="5" indeterminate color="primary"></v-progress-circular>
  </v-layout>
</v-card>
```

Comment: yeah this works :) let's see if there is a "better" solution or if I should go for my own custom CSS

Answer (score 2):

```
<v-card overlay-opacity="0.15">
  <...>
</v-card>
```